# What does "bloc" refer to in "oversees the sprawling arm of the bloc that negotiates trade deals and commercial policy"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/finance/news/brexit-valdis-dombrovskis-becomes-eu-trade-chief-as-ireland-loses-crucial-portfolio-083511302.html) I am confused "which bloc" the line mentions if it is the bloc of the Ireland or the EU.

> Hogan’s appointment to the role, **which oversees the sprawling arm of the bloc that negotiates trade deals and commercial policy,** had been seen as a powerful signal that the EU would prioritise Ireland’s interests in Brexit negotiations.

Comment: It would make no sense if the bloc were Ireland, because the role that’s being talked about is that of EU Trade Commissioner. The EU Commission can’t be seen as an arm of Ireland.

Comment: There is no such thing as "the bloc of Ireland" anyway.  A bloc is a group of allied countries.  Although the island of Ireland contains two jurisdictions, they have never been referred to or regarded as a bloc (and only the Republic of Ireland is being referred to in the article anyway).  So yes, it's the EU.

Comment: @MikeScott Thanks. My aged brain read such somehow^^.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of the article reads:

> European Commission president Ursula von der Leyen on Tuesday said that she had appointed Valdis Dombrovskis as **the EU**’s trade chief, a pivotal role in **the bloc** amid stalled Brexit negotiations and global trade tensions.

Here the "bloc" refers to the [European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union) as a trade bloc, and so does it in your quoted sentence.

Edit: additional information from comments:

"Hogan’s appointment to the role" here the author is talking about when Hogan was appointed as commissioner in 2019. The clause "which oversees the sprawling arm of the bloc" is in the present simple because it describes the role of the office, as opposed to what Hogan did in that position. Taking that clause out from that sentence we get "Hogan’s appointment to the role ... had been seen as a powerful signal". It is talking about something that happened in the past because as you have noted Hogan does not hold that office any more.

Comment: It's mainly American journalists that call the EU 'the bloc'.